# What is a Webhook and why should I care?

Tags: http, web, webhooks

Best I could find was this [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook)

I I thought "surely there must be more to it than this".

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [doc](https://webhooks.pbworks.com/w/page/13385124/FrontPage):

> **What is WebHook?**
>
> The concept of a WebHook is simple. A WebHook is an HTTP callback: an
> HTTP POST that occurs when something happens; a simple event-notification via HTTP POST.
>
> A web application implementing WebHooks will POST a message to a URL
> when certain things happen. When a web application enables users to
> register their own URLs, the users can then extend, customize, and
> integrate that application with their own custom extensions or even
> with other applications around the web. For the user, WebHooks are a
> way to receive valuable information when it happens, rather than
> continually polling for that data and receiving nothing valuable most
> of the time. WebHooks have enormous potential and are limited only by
> your imagination! (No, it can't wash the dishes. Yet.)
>
> **Why should I care?**
>
> As integrated as we perceive the web, most web applications today
> operate in silos. With the rise of API's we've seen mashups and some
> degree of integration between applications. However, we have not seen
> the vision of the programmable web: a web where you as the user can
> "pipe" data between apps much like the Unix command line. Some say RSS
> is the answer. They are wrong. The heart is in the right place, but
> the implementation is wrong. RSS is still useful, but it is not going
> to bring us the true programmable web.
>
> We just need a simple way to get data out in real-time to let the user easily do whatever >they wantwith it. That means no polling, no content constraints, and no XML
> parsing. That means no RSS. Using HTTP is simpler and easier to use.
> PHP is a very popular and accessible programming environment, so it's
> likely to be used often for writing hooklets... getting data from a
> web POST in PHP is as simple as $_POST['something']. And making the
> request to the user script is as simple as making an HTTP request,
> something already built-in to most programming environments. In fact,
> web hooks are easier to implement than an API.