# Is it safe to communicate with WCF service from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, wcf

There is a Windows service that I need to communicate with (in a duplex way) from ASP.NET. Is it safe to turn the Windows service into a WCF service and organize two-way communication?

I'm concerned about a scenario when the service is trying to communicate but ASP.NET process is getting reloaded and the message gets lost. Though it's unlikely during development, I guess it's quite likely in production with many clients.

I'm leaning towards a solution that involves some kind of persistence:

1. Both the Windows service and ASP.NET write data to SQL Server and get notified via `SqlDependency`
2. They exchange messages via RabbitMq

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple of ideas regarding the general case where two independent systems (processes, servers, etc.) need to communicate reliably:

1. **Transaction model**, where the transmitting party initiates communication and waits for acknowledgment from the recipient before marking the message as delivered. In case of transmission failure/timeout, it's the sender's responsibility to persist the message and retry later. For instance, [Webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644019/what-is-a-webhook-and-why-should-i-care) architectures rely on this model.
2. **Publish/Subscribe model**, used by a lot of distributed systems, where both parties rely on a third-party message broker (message queue/service bus mechanism) such as RabbitMQ. In this architecture, sender is only responsible for making sure that the message has been successfully queued. The responsibility of making sure that the message is delivered to the recipient is on the message broker. In this case, you need to make sure that your message broker satisfies your reliability needs, for example: Is it in-memory only? Or does it also persist to disk and is able to recover from not just a process-recycle but also a power/system recycle.

And like you said, you can build your own messaging infrastructure too: sender writes to a local or cloud database or a cloud queue/service bus, and the receiver polls and consumes the messages.

So, a few guidelines:

1. If you ever need to scale out (have multiple servers) and they need to somehow collaborate on these messages, then make your initial investment on a database or cloud-queue solution (such as Azure SQL or Azure Queues).
2. Otherwise, if your services only need to communicate within one server, then you can use a database approach or use a queue service that satisfies your persistence/reliability requirements. RabbitMQ seems like a robust solution for this scenario.